# Verificar se window load é false

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Quando eu dou o comando:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    console.log('Site totalmente carregado!');
});
```

Funciona corretamente, a mensagem no console so aparece quando a janela foi totalmente  carregada.
  Mas por exemplo, como verifico se esse `(window).load()` é false?

Quando utilizo:

```
while(!$(window).load()){
    console.log('Carregando...');
}
```

Ele meio que não da o comando como false. Por que?

Comment: Podes explicar porque queres fazer isso? Tenho dúvidas pois acho que pode outro cominho melhor

Comment: Miguel, vou criar um mini sistema, somente pra ter um loading enquanto o site está carregando. Sei que posso criar um div sobrepondo todo o site e esconder no final do window load, mas, fiquei com essa dúvida, pôs estava testando os comando no console.log e não me retornaram resultados de true ou false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu costumo fazer de maneira simples sem jQuery assim:

```js
function domReady(cb) {
  (function checkDomReady() {
    var state = document.readyState;
    if (state == 'loaded' || state == 'complete') cb();
    else setTimeout(checkDomReady, 200);
  })();
};

domReady(function() {
  console.log('a página já carregou!');
});
```

A ideia é ter uma função que se chama a si própria até a página ter mudado de estado. Esta lógica permite chamar `domReady` várias vezes de sítios diferentes. A função que for passada a `domReady` é chamada quando a página tiver com estado `loaded` ou `complete`.

Para teres um loader é só adicionares uma classe a um elemento do DOM que seja retirada dentro da função passada a `domReady`.

Por exemplo assim:

```js
document.body.classList.add('a-carregar');

setTimeout(() => {
  document.body.classList.remove('a-carregar');
}, 3000);
```

```css
body.a-carregar {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Maneiro, Sergio, entendi! So tenho algumas dúvidas, por que você usou uma function dentro de outra? Não era somente criar a function domReady? Por exemplo: (Aqui vai ficar meio embolado, mas acho que da pra entender se copiar e colar)

Comment: function domReady(cb) {
    var state = document.readyState;
    if (state == 'loaded' || state == 'complete') cb();
    else setTimeout(checkDomReady, 200);
};

Comment: Desculpa se fui leigo, estou meio que "entrando agora" em JavaScript/JQuery

Comment: @LucasCarvalho é para poder ir chamando a sí próprio guardando o `cb` na memória até ser altura de chamar.

Answer (score 2):

Método `load` possui os seguintes parâmetros `.load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )`

exemplo de funcionamento

```
$( "#success" ).load( "/not-here.php", function( response, status, xhr ) {
  if ( status == "error" ) {
    var msg = "Ocorreu o seguinte erro ";
    $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
  }
});
```

Como pode ver, error é equivalente a false em `load`, significa que não foi possível requisitar tal informação. Caso queira acompanhar o processo use `beforeSend` em uma requisição `ajax`...

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('.loading').html('Carregando...');
    }
});
```

Consulte [Load](http://api.jquery.com/load/),
[Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

Existem dois `.load` no JQuery. O primeiro, que você pode ver [aqui](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) é um event handler para o evento "load" do JavaScript. Ele é chamado quando um componente e todos seus subcomponentes forem carregados totalmente. Esse método foi ***deprecated*** a partir do JQuery 1.8 e removido a partir do JQuery 3.0.

O outro método `.load`, que pode ser visto [aqui](http://api.jquery.com/load/), é um método do módulo Ajax responsável por carregar um HTML de um servidor e colocar o conteúdo no componente onde foi chamado o método. Antes do primeiro ser ***deprecated***, o JQuery sabia qual método estava sendo chamado de acordo com os parâmetros informados.

Nenhum desses métodos retornam simplesmente `true` ou `false` como você está querendo (o primeiro `.load` citado retorna um objeto JQuery). O que pode ser feito é colocar o código que você quer executar após toda a página ser carregada dentro da função `.ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // fazer alguma coisa
});
```

Tudo que estiver fora desse método será executado antes da página ser totalmente carregada.