# Função dentro de função

Tags: javascript, jquery

Esses dias, fiz uma pergunta aqui no SOpt e [o rapaz me respondeu com um código, criando uma função dentro de outra função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/244582/129), algo simples, mas eu não usava isso, e passei a implementar.

```
function QuantosEmEstoqueAbrir(){
    $j('.availability-only').attr("style", "transform: translate(0);");
    function QuantosEmEstoqueFechar(){
        $j('.availability-only').attr("style", "transform: translate(300px);");
    } setTimeout(QuantosEmEstoqueFechar, 10000);
}
setTimeout(QuantosEmEstoqueAbrir, 10000);
```

Isso é uma "mini notificação" que fiz para um sistema de uma loja, e está funcionando tudo bem!

Mas minha dúvida é a seguinte, olhando o código mencionado acima, que o rapaz me deu como resposta:

```
function domReady(cb) {
  (function checkDomReady() {
    var state = document.readyState;
    if (state == 'loaded' || state == 'complete') cb();
    else setTimeout(checkDomReady, 200);
  })();
};
```

Ele usou a função dele entre parenteses. Por que disso?

```
 (function checkDomReady() {
    var state = document.readyState;
    if (state == 'loaded' || state == 'complete') cb();
    else setTimeout(checkDomReady, 200);
  })
```

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicata [Sobre (function(){ … }()) e callThis()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23785/18246)

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicata [Qual a utilidade do Ponto de Exclamação (!) antes de se declarar funções em Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157145/18246)

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicata [Qual a diferença entre criar um módulo normalmente e criar um módulo dentro de uma função?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120727/18246)

Answer (score 1):

O parênteses em volta da função é porquê essa é uma função auto executável. Note que logo após o parênteses em volta, ela esta se executando **( )**

```
(function checkDomReady() {
var state = document.readyState;
if (state == 'loaded' || state == 'complete') cb();
else setTimeout(checkDomReady, 200);
})();
```

Se você rodar sem os parêntheses em volta, você terá um erro de sintaxe:

```
function checkDomReady() {
var state = document.readyState;
if (state == 'loaded' || state == 'complete') cb();
else setTimeout(checkDomReady, 200);
}();
```

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

No site do BrazilJS tem um artigo explicando melhor, caso interessar: https://braziljs.org/blog/funcoes-em-javascript/

Espero ter ajudado.